# How to allow oneday delivery option for specific zipcodes?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I need to allow oneday delivery option for specific zipcodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default shipping method "Table Rate" for this. In this shipping method you can import csv file for that zipcodes. and set your rates and shipping label there. 
OR
You can use webshop matrix shipping method for this.
Both are same related to functionality

Comment: Whats the issue you are facing ?

Comment: I accepted your answer. it worked for me, i changed the country code as IN. now worked. you correct answered here. accepted and up voted